# get repetitive string in python with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to get a repetitive string in this example with regex (python):

```
#txt1#txt2#txt3#txt4
```

I tested with this pattern:

```
\#(.*?)
```

but don't work
Thank you

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4

Comment: don't feel you need a regex here: `'#txt1#txt2#txt3#txt4'.strip('#').split('#')`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Perhaps, there can be  cases like `text0#text1#text2` and `text0` is not an expected value in the result. Or is a part of a larger regex pattern.

Comment: please post an example of code.

Comment: Please don't change the question into another one. Ask a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy dot pattern `.*?` at the end of a pattern always matches an empty string because `.*?` matches *as few as possible* occurrences of the quantified pattern, and since it can match 0 chars, it matches 0 chars.

## Single char scenario

For strings having `#` delimited values, you may use a negated character class `[^#]` with a `*` quantifier:

```
import re
s = '#txt1#txt2#txt3#txt4'
print(re.findall(r"#([^#]*)", s))
# => ['txt1', 'txt2', 'txt3', 'txt4']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SDLGmf).

The [`#([^#]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/4gp01B/1) pattern  matches a `#` and then matches and captures into Group 1 any 0+ characters other than `#`. `re.findall` finds all non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern and only returns the values captured into Group 1.

**NOTE**: To make sure you do not get empty values in the result, you should replace the `*` quantifier with a `+` one that matches *1 or more occurrences*.

## Multi-char delimiters

In this case, you should choose a splitting approach. In case you have just a hard-coded delimiter, like `#|`, all you need is `str.split()`:

```
s = '#|txt1#|txt2#|txt3#|txt4'
res = filter(None, s.split('#|'))
print(res)
# => ['txt1', 'txt2', 'txt3', 'txt4']
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/3I0T6a). Note that `filter(None, res)` will remove all empty strings from the `res`.

If you have  a delimiter that is not hard-coded, you may use a `re.split`.

Comment: Probably shorter: `'[^#]+'`

Comment: Yes, that is what I have been adding. But that is not actually clear, whether OP wants to match those empty strings or not.

Comment: @RohanAmrute For this exact case, yes. In the OP, there is only an input string, and a pattern that seems to be designed to match any text after `#`. It seems reasonable to use a negated character class in this scenario. There are other possible ways to match it, splitting with `#` will also work here, but I am focusing on why the original regex does not work and explain what the regex way is to solve it.

Comment: if the text is like this '#|txt1#|txt2#|txt3#|txt4' and txt1,txt2... can contain # or | i can't use negative character , (thankyou)

Comment: @RguezYasser: And what is the rule then? How do you explain the pattern you need in words? Do you want to get substrings between `#|` symbols?

Comment: @RguezYasser: But what is the delimiter pattern then? I have seen such strings before, but you should be more precise. Please add this real string into the question and add expected output.

Comment: @RguezYasser Why did you post that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674041/get-strings-list-in-python-with-regex)? If you have `¬~` as delimiter, use `filter(None, s.split('¬~'))`. You do not need a regex. Of course, you may use `filter(None, re.split(r'¬~', s))`, but it makes no sense.