# Get strings list in python with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want extract strings from this text with **regex**:

```
¬~ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷~World¬~AA÷Eef~RZgth¬AD¬~AA÷jaKNedK8¬AD÷1502690‌​400¬ADE÷~1502690400
```

expected output:

```
['ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷~World','AA÷Eef~RZgth¬AD','AA÷j‌​aKNedK8¬AD÷150269040‌​0¬ADE÷~1502690400']
```

the delimiter is

```
¬~
```

Thankyou

Comment: The question is off-topic due to lack of supporting efforts. Please see [ask] or take a [tour].

Comment: See https://ideone.com/JuXfV4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task using a regex is a bit overkill.
Just use the split() method

```
string = "¬~ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷~World¬~AA÷Eef~RZgth¬AD¬~AA÷jaKNedK8¬AD÷1502690‌​400¬ADE÷~1502690400"
x = string.split("¬~")
print(x)
```